# How to get instance name from jenkins script console?

Tags: jenkins, groovy

How to get the instance name from Jenkins script console by writing groovy script.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a couple of system information in your Jenkins under `https://your.jenkins.instance/manage/systemInfo`. Every variable that is defined there you can print in the script console like this:

```
println(System.getenv("COMPUTERNAME"))
```